# PHP Ping tool second If or Else statement

Tags: php, html

Im quite new to web development and am making a php ping tool to see what sites we have up or down. as we have 115 sites I chose to only display the sites that are down. On the webpage when no sites are down or not replying to pings can I have it display a message saying something like "There are no sites down" or something. This is php with bootstrap styling.

```
$counter = "";
foreach ($host1 as $value1) 

{

 $counter = $counter + 1;
  echo "<tr>"; 
  echo '<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" text="#000000"></body>';       
  //check target IP or domain
  $pingreply = exec("ping -n $count $value1");
  if ( substr($pingreply, -2) == 'ms')
    {

    }
  else 
    {
        #echo "<td width=60><strong><font color='#990000'>DOWN</font></strong></td>";
        echo "<p><fstrong textont size='6'><center><strong><div class='alert alert-danger'>" . $services1[$counter] . " - No Reply</div></strong></center></font></p>";
    }
}
```

Is anyone able to help me with this, Im not sure how to add a second else or second if statement to this code.

Comment: Add a flag. If at least one site is down - set flag to true. If after the loop flag is still false - you have NO sites down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in comment:

```
$counter = "";
$has_down = false;   // flag, no sites are down yet
foreach ($host1 as $value1) 
{
  $counter = $counter + 1;
  echo "<tr>"; 
  echo '<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" text="#000000"></body>';       
  //check target IP or domain
  $pingreply = exec("ping -n $count $value1");
  if ( substr($pingreply, -2) == 'ms')
    {

    }
  else 
    {
        #echo "<td width=60><strong><font color='#990000'>DOWN</font></strong></td>";
        echo "<p><fstrong textont size='6'><center><strong><div class='alert alert-danger'>" . $services1[$counter] . " - No Reply</div></strong></center></font></p>";
        // site down, set flag
        $has_down = true;
    }
}

// flag still false, all sites work
if (!$has_down) {
    echo 'There are no sites down';
}
```

Comment: That's perfect! Thanks a lot for that I can use this for so much now.

Comment: If the answer solves your problem - accept/upvote it.

Comment: Hi Mulder I have another very quick question, I believe this only sends 1 packet ping. In this code am I able to increase the amount of pings it sends as some of these sites are on ADSL Connections and drop pings all the time so its showing them as down even when there not. Was wondering if I can increase the amount of times it pings to stop this from happening.